# Django sending email with dynamic SMTP settings

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make EMAIL_HOST settings configurable within admin and I will create a model with required fields like:

- EMAIL_HOST
- EMAIL_HOST_USER
- EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
- EMAIL_PORT

But how can I use those fields in views using send_mail?

Comment: FYI: [dynamic-django-mail-configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281865/dynamic-django-mail-configuration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `send_mail`, you'll have to create your own [email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend) which uses your custom settings and then pass it to `send_mail` in the `connection` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```py
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend

config = Configuration.objects.get(**lookup_kwargs)

try:

    backend = EmailBackend(
        host=config.host,
        port=config.port,
        password=config.password,
        username=config.username,
        use_tls=config.use_tls,
        fail_silently=config.fail_silently
    )

    mail = EmailMessage(
        subject="subject",
        body="body",
        from_email=config.username,
        to=["email@gmail.com"],
        connection=backend,
    )
    mail.send()

except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending mail with **a custom configured SMTP setting in the admin page which is independent of the Django setting:**

```
from django.core import mail
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend
from <'Your SMTP setting in admin'> import <'Your model'>

def send_mail(subject, contact_list, body): 
    try:
        con = mail.get_connection()
        con.open()
        print('Django connected to the SMTP server')
        mail_setting = <'Your model'>.objects.last()
        host = mail_setting.host
        host_user = mail_setting.host_user
        host_pass = mail_setting.host_pass
        host_port = mail_setting.host_port
        mail_obj = EmailBackend(
            host=host,
            port=host_port,
            password=host_pass,
            username=host_user,
            use_tls=True,
            timeout=10)
        msg = mail.EmailMessage(
            subject=subject,
            body=body,
            from_email=host_user,
            to=[contact_list],
            connection=con)
        mail_obj.send_messages([msg])
        print('Message has been sent.')
        mail_obj.close()
        return True

    except Exception as _error:
        print('Error in sending mail >> {}'.format(_error))
        return False
```