# Dynamic Django Mail Configuration

Tags: python, django, email

I don't want to use email configuration fields in setting.py, i want to put them in to a model.

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    email_use_tls = models.BooleanField(_(u'EMAIL_USE_TLS'),default=True)
    email_host = models.CharField(_(u'EMAIL_HOST'),max_length=1024)
    email_host_user = models.CharField(_(u'EMAIL_HOST_USER'),max_length=255)
    email_host_password = models.CharField(_(u'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD'),max_length=255)
    email_port = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_(u'EMAIL_PORT'),default=587)
    ....
```

What is the best practice to configure django.core.mail.send_mail behaviour? Should i copy send_mail code to my project? Thats not what i want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very interesting question. It seems like this is already implemented in EmailMessage class.

First you need to configure email backend

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import EmailBackend


config = Configuration.objects.get(**lookup_kwargs)

backend = EmailBackend(host=config.host, port=congig.port, username=config.username, 
                       password=config.password, use_tls=config.use_tls, fail_silently=config.fail_silently)
```

Then just pass connection to EmailMessage

```
email = EmailMessage(subject='subj', body='body', from_email=from_email, to=to, 
             connection=backend)
```

Then send email :)

```
email.send()
```

Ofc if you want html or file attachments use EmailMultiAlternatives instead

Answer (score 2):

There is little error in the answer above (Andrey Nelubin's answer). No need to call `get_connection(backend=backend)`. You should pass backend to the `EmailMessage` constructor, like this:

```
backend = EmailBackend(host=config.host, port=congig.port, username=config.username, 
                               password=config.password, use_tls=config.use_tls, fail_silently=config.fail_silently)
email = EmailMessage(subject='subj', body='body', from_email=from_email, to=to, 
                 connection=backend)
```

I can not add comment that answer and dicided to post new one. Please someone who have permissions move it there or correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method for a few years and love it. I've just published a package ([`django-des`](https://github.com/jamiecounsell/django-des)) to accomplish this using the methods in the other answers here.

This package installs a model (`DynamicEmailConfiguration`) and uses `django-solo` to give you a nice editing experience in the Django admin. It then provides an email backend you can use that will pull settings from that model in a similar way to what Andrey Nelubin recommended. It also gives you a nice little test email button at the top right of the Django Admin Panel.

To install it:

- Install Django Dynamic Email Settings:

  ```
  $ pip install django-des
  ```
- Add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      ...
      'django_des',
      ...
  )
  ```
- Add the dynamic email configuration email backend to settings.py

  ```
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_des.backends.ConfiguredEmailBackend'
  ```
- To enable test email support, add Django DES's URL patterns:

  ```
  from django_des import urls as django_des_urls

  urlpatterns = [
      ...
      url(r'^django-des/', include(django_des_urls)),
  ]
  ```

Now you can visit [127.0.0.1:8000/admin/django_des/dynamicemailconfiguration/](http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/django_des/dynamicemailconfiguration/) and configure your email settings. You can send a test email from there too.

Once this is all done, you can use `send_mail` normally.