# How to set SMTP for customer in production?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-email

What is the best practice for setting customer's SMTP in Django?

Can I make them to set itself? I can't do that inside settings, otherwise they would have to tell me their password.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
```

Is there a way? Maybe allow them to set credentials through Django admin?

**EDIT:**

For now, the best way looks like to create a singleton object, let's call it `config`, to store credentials and register it in admin page to allow admins to set their credentials. Then, create one class for sending messages and do something like that:

```
backend = EmailBackend(host=config.host, port=config.port, username=config.username, 
                           password=config.password, use_tls=config.use_tls, fail_silently=config.fail_silently)
email = EmailMessage(subject='subj', body='body', from_email=from_email, to=to, 
             connection=backend)
```

like here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287776/3371056

But maybe there is some pattern to do such thing differently.

Answer (score 0):

if you want save it in database like a config,[django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) is recommended,the advantage is you can edit and only can edit(no add\delete interface) it by admin.

here is the code you get conf in views.py by django-constance if you use it:

```
from constance import LazyConfig
config = LazyConfig()


def put_value(key, value):
    setattr(config, key, value)


def get_value(key):
    return getattr(config, key)
```